# Count statement not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to check if the user who's trying to connect exists. For that, I use a count sql statement which doesn't seem to work:

```
Integer count = ((Long)session.createQuery("select count(*) from bi_membres where login = '" +
                this.login + "' and motPasse = '" + this.motPasse + "'").uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

I'm getting a `SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` error. In this example, let's say I'm trying to connect myself as 'art' with my password being 'ar'.

**Stack trace**

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:942)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:909)
at com.deptinfo.beans.ConnexionBean.verifierConnexion(ConnexionBean.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (login='art' )and(motPasse='ar' )' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
```

Here's the line that caught my attention:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (login='art' )and(motPasse='ar' )' at line 1
```

The strange part is that i tried the same query (with parentheses) in localhost and it worked fine.

**Bi_membres table mapping conf (simplified)**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.deptinfo.classes.BiMembres" table="bi_membres" catalog="bibli" optimistic-lock="version">
    <property name="login" type="string">
      <column name="Login" length="20" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="motPasse" type="string">
      <column name="MotPasse" length="10" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

By the way, don't mind the password not being encrypted, not part of the assignment.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

**Edit**

I changed my query to make it a prepared one:

```
String hqlNbMembres = "select count(*) from Bi_membres membre where membre.login=:login and membre.motPasse=:motPasse";
Integer count = ((Long)session.createQuery(hqlNbMembres).setString("login", this.login).setString("motPasse", this.motPasse).uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
QueryException: in expected: membre [select count(*) from Bi_membres membre where membre.login=:login and membre.motPasse=:motPasse]
```

Any hint?

Comment: **USE A PREPARED QUERY**. Building queries by hand is not only **extremely dangerous** but also error prone.

Comment: Okay, I thought it wouldn't change much, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Also, [RTFM](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-aggregation). This is invalid HQL for reasons other than your manual variable substitution.

Comment: Ok I changed to prepared query and I read your linked documentation, but I'm still getting an error. I'm blocked there. See my edit.

Comment: createQuery -> createNativeQuery (as Boris the Spider said, this is invalid HQL) or read more about HQL

Comment: with a session use createSQLQuery

Comment: Alright, thanks that finally worked. But I still don't understand why my query wasn't valid HQL. Is it because I had something before "from"?

Comment: HQL operates with java entities, not database objects. HQL != SQL, it just gives a similar way to get data from a db using java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Projection.

```
Criteria crit=session.createCriteria(BiMembres.class);
        crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("login", this.login));
       ... OTHER Criterias if any..
       //set the count projection
      crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
   Long rowsCount = (Long)crit.uniqueResult();
```